# Unable to install pdo pdo_mysql using Docker Compose

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

My docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mariadb1
            MYSQL_USER: user1
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass1
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass1
    php-fpm:
        image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
        build: .
        # command: docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
        # command: docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
        command: docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
        volumes:
            - ./mysite:/var/www/html:delegated
```

Then I start the compose using

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up --abort-on-container-exit
```

Error I get

```
Aborting on container exit...
[+] Running 3/3
 ⠿ Container wp_nginx-nginx-1    Stopped                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 ⠿ Container wp_nginx-php-fpm-1  Stopped                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 ⠿ Container wp_nginx-mysql-1    Stopped                                                                                                                                   0.3s
ERRO[0019] 0
```

My ultimate aim is to run PHP site (wordpress) using Nginx and MySQL/MariaDB. This is why I am trying to get the PMP-FTM having the PDO drivers setup.

Any thoughts/suggestions please?

Comment: Unless that container base has the MySQL client libraries, it may not be able to proceed.

Comment: when I use ``command:`` it seems the FPM doesn't finish its service. So far that's what I find. And there's not much room for me to have two ``command:`` sequences. Still trying to find a way...

Comment: It's not a matter of more command sequences, it's about finding a container with the correct libraries or building your own that does, at least if the library is the issue. I'm pretty sure that's the case, but I could be wrong. Try spinning up the container and doing the installation process manually, carefully observing the errors it reports, before trying to automate with Docker Compose.

Comment: I agree. That's what has happened, its basically wasn't able to execute the required command as I have overridden. Now fixed, I'll post what worked for me soon as I got it a bit cleaned up. Thanks for thought provoking. Quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use a Dockerfile (Let's call this file Dockerfile-phpfm).

```
# Setup GD extension
RUN apk add --no-cache \
      freetype \
      libjpeg-turbo \
      libpng \
      freetype-dev \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
      --with-freetype=/usr/include/ \
      --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd \
    && apk del --no-cache \
      freetype-dev \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

RUN apk add libzip-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli zip bcmath
```

Then use that file in my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mariadb1
            MYSQL_USER: user1
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass1
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass1
        volumes:
        - ./wp_db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    php-fpm:
        # image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-phpfpm
        volumes:
            - ./wpsite:/var/www/html:delegated
```

No more errors and works fine for me. Thanks @tadman for the chat, helps me think more, especially the part "it's about finding a container with the correct libraries or building your own".